# how to configure cert file and key file on micronaut similar to quarkus

Tags: ssl, quarkus, micronaut

I have an existing cert and key files that I use on quarkus like
`quarkus.http.ssl.certificate.key-files=key-file` as it is on documantation Quarkus config docs but micronaut does not seem to have similar setup but requres java keystore or am I missing something? Here is the micronaut reference documentation https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/guide/configurationreference.html

Comment: Hope it helps: https://quarkus.io/guides/http-reference#ssl

Comment: Hi @zforgo, yes I have done it on quarkus but I would like to know how to do the same on micronaut without having to use keystore.